# Data packed in ugly way in R

Tags: r, tibble

I have this tidying problem that simply won't go away, really have no idea how to go about it right now.

I have a tibble in which the first column Id stores an integer ID, and the second column values goes something like this:
"2.3(09/13)2.6(10/14)2.9(4/15)"
So it goes Numeric(Date)Numeric(Date)Numeric(Date) and so on.

The problem is, I have no way to determine how many times this pattern will repeat.

Example data:

1        0.2(01/17)0.19(02/17)0.254(03/17)0.26(07/17)0.217(09/17)0.72(11/17)0.896(11/17)

2        0.144(06/17)0.171(08/17)0.21(11/17)

What I'm looking for is something like:
1     0.2   01/17
1     0.19  02/17
1     0.254 03/17
...

What I'd like to do is to transform this in something like a long-formatted list.
I tried using

```
separate(tibble,
         col = "values",
         into = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","l"),
         sep=c("\\(","\\)")
)
```

and I could get it to work, if I use `pivot_longer` after this, but the problem started interesting me so now I'm trying to solve it in a nicer way.

I've always only studied Java and the likes, so this kind of logic is very new to me.

Thanks!

...And sorry I have no idea how to format the data into tables.

EDIT: Sorry I wasn't clear in explaining how I had my data formatted!
Correct formatting is c(1,2),c(0.2(01/17)0.19(02/17)0.254(03/17)0.26(07/17)0.217(09/17)0.72(11/17)0.896(11/17),0.144(06/17)0.171(08/17)0.21(11/17))
Sorry about that, but I could get the answer from @jay.sf to work, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R approach, arranging `strsplit` result into a matrix.

```
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, Map(function(x, y)
  transform(data.frame(id=y, matrix(el(strsplit(x, "[()]")), ncol=2, b=T)),
            X1=as.numeric(levels(X1))[X1]), 
  Map(`[`, strsplit(x, " "), 2), substr(x, 1, 1)))
res
#    id    X1    X2
# 1   1 0.200 01/17
# 2   1 0.190 02/17
# 3   1 0.254 03/17
# 4   1 0.260 07/17
# 5   1 0.217 09/17
# 6   1 0.720 11/17
# 7   1 0.896 11/17
# 8   2 0.144 06/17
# 9   2 0.171 08/17
# 10  2 0.210 11/17
```

---

*Data*

```
x <- c("1 0.2(01/17)0.19(02/17)0.254(03/17)0.26(07/17)0.217(09/17)0.72(11/17)0.896(11/17)",
       "2 0.144(06/17)0.171(08/17)0.21(11/17)")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
do.call('rbind', unlist(
  apply(df, 1, function(x){
    lapply(strsplit(x, ")", fixed = TRUE), function(y) {
      m <- do.call('rbind', strsplit(y, "(", fixed = TRUE))
      m <- as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      names(m) <- c('val', 'date')
      m$val <- as.numeric(m$val)
      m
    })
  } ), recursive = FALSE))


#             val  date
# values.1  0.200 01/17
# values.2  0.190 02/17
# values.3  0.254 03/17
# values.4  0.260 07/17
# values.5  0.217 09/17
# values.6  0.720 11/17
# values.7  0.896 11/17
# values.11 0.144 06/17
# values.21 0.171 08/17
# values.31 0.210 11/17
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text='values
                 1        0.2(01/17)0.19(02/17)0.254(03/17)0.26(07/17)0.217(09/17)0.72(11/17)0.896(11/17)

                 2        0.144(06/17)0.171(08/17)0.21(11/17)', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```